# Translate custom field in countries module

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am using the [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) module in a multilingual site and I added a custom field to it.

The countries itself support translation for its own field, but is there a way to translate content for the custom fields added to it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module to get this to work.

In doing so, if you run into an error like "The entities of type Country do not define a valid base path: it will not be possible to translate them.", then review the issue about "[Countries is not integrating properly with Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1660370)" (status = needs review).